# Multibinding on textbox doesn't work

Tags: wpf, binding

**Both cases were solved, look into 1st answer comments for info.**

This piece of code compiles though gives an error at runtime. Exception says:

`A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll`.

Parse exception happens when I'm trying to set source for the second binding in MultiBinding. I've tried hell of a lot of ways and digged through ~20 articles, though I can't find out what`s wrong in here.

My best guess is that it`s somehow connected to the wrong return type of a converter.

And, btw, when you change TextBox to TextBlock, 1st case works. The second case doesn`t work still.

**CASE1**

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Draft.MainControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:draft="clr-namespace:Draft" 
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
        Height="350" Width="352">

    <UserControl.Resources>

        <s:String x:Key="str1">HELLO</s:String>
        <s:String x:Key="str2">WORLD</s:String>

        <draft:StringConverter x:Key="myStringConverter"/>

     </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>

        <TextBox Name="tb1">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myStringConverter}">
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource str1}" />
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource str2}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
public class StringConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        return ( values[0].ToString() + values[1].ToString() );
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack( object values, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**CASE2**

And another case for the same problem:

> ```
>         <Grid>
>             <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
>
>                 <TextBlock.Resources>
>                     <s:Int32 x:Key="defaultHeight">2</s:Int32>
>                     <s:Int32 x:Key="defaultNum">10</s:Int32>
>                     <draft:MultiplierConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
>                 </TextBlock.Resources>
>
>                 <TextBlock.Text>
>                     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&#10;
>                     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&#10;
>                     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&#10;
>                     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&#10;
>                     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&#10;
>                     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&#10;
>                     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&#10;
>                     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&#10;
>                     aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&#10;
>                 </TextBlock.Text>
>
>                 <TextBlock.Height>
>                     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
>                         <Binding Source="{StaticResource defaultNum}" Mode="OneWay" />
>                         <Binding Source="{StaticResource defaultHeight}" Mode="OneWay" />
>                     </MultiBinding>
>                 </TextBlock.Height>
>             </TextBlock>
>         </Grid>
>     </UserControl>
> ```

```
Code behind:
```

> ```
>   public class MultiplierConverter : IMultiValueConverter
>   {
>       public object Convert( object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
>       {
>           if ( values.Count() == 2 && values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue )
>           {
>               var num = (Int32)values[0];
>               var height = (Int32)values[1];
>
>               return ( num * height );
>           }
>
>           return 0;
>       }
>
>       public object[] ConvertBack( object values, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
>       {
>           throw new NotImplementedException();
>       }
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't significantly change your question when it has already been answered. That's really confusing! Better ask another question. Then, what exactly means "the second case doesn`t work still"? Do you also get a XamlParseException there?

Comment: Sorry for the change, but I can`t answer my own question for 7 more hours due to low rating (I`m newbee here).

The second case did compile and worked with no error, though height of TextBlock just did not change like it should have because of my multiBinding. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set `Mode="OneWay"` on the inner bindings:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myStringConverter}">
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource str1}" Mode="OneWay" />
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource str2}" Mode="OneWay" />
</MultiBinding>
```

---

If you had investigated the `XamlParseException` in your debugger, you would have realized that there was an [InnerException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) with this message:

> Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.

---

Now for your second problem: When you look at the Output Window in Visual Studio, you might observe the following message:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is
>   not valid for target property.; Value='20'
>   MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'Height' (type 'Double')

I guess that says it all.

You should perhaps pay attention to the `targetType` parameter passed to the `Convert` method. In your case it is `System.Double`.

Comment: And is there a way to set path instead? Or such constants do not have one? Something like

<Binding Source="{StaticResource str2}" Path="Value" />

does exist?

Comment: You're binding to a `string`, which has nothing like a `Value` property. Hence you can't set the `Path` of the binding. Even then a string would be immutable, which would force you to use one-way binding anyway.

Comment: I see, thank you. The 1st case is solved by replacing TextBox with TextBlock, the second doesn`t work although.

Comment: Your advice is also good:

you either use TextBox with Mode="OneWay" or use TextBlock with no concern of Mode

Comment: Yes of course, since two-way binding doesn't make any sense on a TextBlock. There is no user input and hence nothing that can trigger the binding in source direction. That is why the `TextBlock.Text` property binds one-way, whereas the `TextBox.Text` property binds two-way by default.

Comment: I see now, haven`t thought of this default Mode-s.

The CASE2 problem was also solved: WPF wants you to use EXACTLY the acquired return-types!!! In MSDN documentation i found out that Height property is DOUBLE. I expected that my INT result would be silently cast to double, cause it`s safe (at least in one-way mode). But it was not. So you should write something like "return (double)20" instead of "return 20" in converter. Lifehack, FML.